# Django local memory cache is re-fetching each time

Tags: django, django-views, django-cache

I am using Django's local memory cache in development and I can't get it to work. I have set the following in settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
 'default': {
             'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'
  }
}
```

I see the views are being called everytime a page is loaded. I only have *one* Django server process running in dev

Answer (score 1):

Next step is to *use* the cache (by setting up a per-site cache, per-view cache etc.). For example to cache [the entire site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache), use the following middleware in `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Hey, I am using per site caching but the cache does not get updated before expiration if any data is added/deleted/updated? This doesn't take care of it automatically?

Comment: @reindeer no thats the idea of cache. It will use the cache until the cache expires (unless we refresh the cache)